# how to add value in txt file with php

Tags: php

I want to add a value (not overwrite!) to a txt file with `file_put_contents`

This is what i have so far:

```
$fileUserId = fopen("fileUserId.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$UserIdtxt = $UserID."||";
file_put_contents("fileUserId.txt", $UserIdtxt, FILE_APPEND);
fclose($fileUserId);
```

`$UserID` is an integer, like 1, 2, 3 etc.

So when the the UserID is 1, the **fileUserId.txt** looks like this:

`1||`

When there is another user with ID 2, 
the **fileUserId.txt** should look like this:

`1||2||`

But he overwrites the file so it becomes this:

`2||`

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `fopen` and `fclose` line and you are fine. `file_put_contents` does this internally. And `fopen("fileUserId.txt", "w")` clears the file.

Note:

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: Well this works fine. the only thing what happens now: he puts a `0` between them; so this is the content of **fileUserId.txt**  `1||0||63||0||24||`

Comment: @JackMaessen  Plus; the last `||` is not really necessary as there is no value after `24`.... Check out the alternative approach below... however, you should accept this as the solution... perhaps it offers you an alternative...

Comment: `1||0||63||0||24||` thats then a anther problem with your code that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can as well do it differently. The commented code below illustrates how:

```
<?php

    $txtFile    = __DIR__ . "/fileUserId.txt";
    $UserID     = 9; //<== THIS VALUE IS FOR TESTING PURPOSES, 
                     //<== YOU SHOULD HAVE ACCESS TO THE ORIGINAL $UserID;

    //CHECK THAT THE FILE EXISTS AT ALL
    if( file_exists($txtFile) ){
        // GET THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE... & STORE IT AS A STRING IN A VARIABLE
        $fileData       = file_get_contents($txtFile);

        // SPLIT THE ENTRIES BY THE DELIMITER (||)
        $arrEntries     = preg_split("#\|\|#", $fileData);

        // ADD THE CURRENT $UserID TO THE $arrEntries ARRAY
        $arrEntries[]   = $UserID;

        // RE-CONVERT THE ARRAY TO A STRING...
        $strData        = implode("||", $arrEntries);

        // SAVE THE TEXT FILE BACK AGAIN...
        file_put_contents($txtFile, $strData);
    }else{
        // IF FILE DOES NOT EXIST ALREADY, SIMPLY CREATE IT
        // AND ADD THE CURRENT $UserID AS THE FIRST ENTRY...
        file_put_contents($txtFile, $UserID);
    }
```

Comment: Like that: Sightseeing way to rome! ;)